pam_tally2.so in common-account locking ssh out on Ubuntu 24.04
I just noticed a strange behavior on Ubuntu 24.04 while applying the CIS level1 script. One of the sections of this script is going to append the following line to the file /etc/pam.d/common-account:
account required pam_tally2.so

Well... After this done, nobody can SSH anymore to the machine and the following message is displayed to the shell:
Connection closed by (IP address of the machine) port 22. 

As soon as the line is commented out to the file, login becomes open again. This behavior was not noticed to the 22.04 LTS version. Does anyone know the reason why?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: The issue has been solved. As told, the change which was troubling the SSH access was the one about /etc/pam.d/common-account file. I had originally appended the following line to that file
account     required      pam_tally2.so

but, as @steeldriver told, the pam_tally2 protocol has been deprecated since the previous 22.04LTS version as described here
In order to address this, you have to replace in the line of the same file the value of pam_tally2.so with pam_faillock.so
  account required pam_faillock.so

here comes the version of installed pam libraries on my machine
ii  libpam-modules:amd64                 1.5.3-5ubuntu5                          amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM

ii  libpam-modules-bin                   1.5.3-5ubuntu5                          amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM - helper binaries

Thanks again for your help here!

AFAIK pam_tally2 was deprecated (in favor of pam_faillock) and removed from the libpam-modules package in 22.04 (see for example pam_tally2 on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04LTS). How did you install the module?

Thanks a lot for your answer! So I think that it was installed by default, I'm using the Canonical image from Azure for amd_64
libpam-modules-bin                   1.5.3-5ubuntu5                          amd64        Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM - helper binaries
I am going to try to replace the module with the faillock

Good news! replacing pam_faillock to pam_tally2 is resolving the issue. Thank you @steeldriver for your assistance :-)

Great! if you have time please consider writing an answer with the details - I've not done the switch myself, and haven't see a clear explanation elsewhere of the exact pam.d changes required.
